# How to check load performance with Protractor?

Tags: angular, performance, webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I writing an app in Angular and one of the features is a search box with code completion. Once the user has typed in the search box, I fetch possible results on an API and display then. **How could I assert the my results doesn't take longer than 1s to be displayed in the page?**

So far, I have tried this code bellow with no success (even using `waitForAngularEnabled(false)`):

*home.po.ts*

```
...
search(schoolName: string) {
  this.input
    .clear()
    .then(() => this.input.sendKeys(schoolName));
}

get results() {
  return element(by.id('_searchResults'));
}

get resultLinks() {
  return this.results
    .all(by.css('li a'));
}
...
```

home.e2e-spec.ts

```
it('should load the school results in less than 1s', () => {
  searchPage.navigateTo();
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

  searchPage.search('col');

  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(searchPage.results), 1000);
  expect(searchPage.resultLinks.count())
    .toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```

*Even when my timeout is 0, the tests still pass!* It seems like it never timeouts! What exactly I'm missing here? Can anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it working as intended. The problem was that my **css selector wasn't quite right, since I had a fixed `li` at the bottom of the list**. That's why the condition on `browser.wait` was always true. I had to add an attribute selector in order to differentiate the dynamic items from the fixed one.

Here is my final page object:

home.po.ts

```
...
search(schoolName: string) {
this.input
    .clear()
    .then(() => this.input.sendKeys(schoolName));
}

get results() {
return element(by.id('_searchResults'));
}

get resultLinks() {
return this.results
    .all(by.css('li a[id^=\'_schoolLink\']'));
}
...
```